# Typescript type assertions and non null checks

Tags: typescript

When we do type assertions, if Typescript knows we cannot be right, it complains. For instance

```
type Counter = (start: number) => number;
let counterProblemDetected = ((start: number) => "yo") as Counter;
```

But when non null checks are enabled, it does not complain about not returning from the function, as it would if we had set the type:

```
// 'strictNullChecks' is on
// Typescript does not complain
let counterProblemNotDetected = ((start: number) => {}) as Counter;
// Typescript complains about 'void' not being assignable to type number 
let counterProblemDetected: Counter = ((start: number) => {})
```

I don't get the logic behind this. I could understand that Typescript does not do any check when we use type assertions, but since it does do some checks (it complains about returning a string in the first example), why does it not complain when returning `undefined` when a number is expected and `strictNullChecks` set to `true` ?

Comment: "if Typescript knows we cannot be right" --- there are really very few cases when using `as` is justified. On the other hand, after few years of developing using TS I cannot remember even a single case when I needed it. Something as simple as in your question certainly does not need it.

Comment: @zerkms I'm new to TypeScript, this question was inspired by a sample seen in the documentation (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#hybrid-types) where they use type assertion to define properties on a function (hybrid type).

Comment: Right. I would recommend you to not focus on it too much then, I personally think `as` is dangerous: if you're a beginner there is really almost zero chance you know better than compiler; if you're so advanced so that you know better than compiler _for real_ - you don't need anyone's help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type assertions are allowed when you are down-casting (ie. you are casting a base type to a subtype). Given the structural nature of the typescript system, the function type `(start: number) => number` is a subtype of `(start: number) => void`, so this means you can assert that `(start: number) => void` is actually `(start: number) => number`.

As mentioned in comments it's best to avoid type assertions unless you have a very good reason to use a type assertion (for example the compiler can't figure out something you know to be true). In your examples you should just put the type annotation on the variable, this will make typescript check the type correctly.